# Is there a way to reset the qa.sockets.stackexchange.com web sockets?

Tags: support, web-sockets

If I send multiple (for ex.) 1-question-123 -124 -125 I get back realtime updates for those questions, already tried, and it works. Stack Overflow refresh the page each time you enter a page, so the WS is created again.

But in my case I have the same WS open all the time, is there anyway to reset the subscribed events? Or unsubscribe to some? Or do I need to recreate the WS?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can unsubscribe from an event by prepending the action with a single dash (-).

So if you subscribed to `155-questions-active` to get the realtime question feed
you can unsubscribe by sending `-155-questions-active`.

see [How do the Stack Exchange WebSockets work? What are all the options you can send to them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218343/how-do-the-stack-exchange-websockets-work-what-are-all-the-options-you-can-send) to get all the actions you can send to the websocket.

Here is small Stack Snippet to demo subscription and unsubscription:

```js
var w = new WebSocket("wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/"),
    result = document.getElementById('result'),
    control = document.getElementById('control');
//handle a message
w.onmessage = function(e) { 
    var raw;
    data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (data.data !== "hb") {
       data.data = JSON.parse(data.data);
       raw=document.createElement('div');
       raw.textContent= data.action + 
         ': ' + 
         (data.data.html || 
          data.data.titleEncodedFancy || 
          data.data.body);
       result.appendChild(raw);
    } else {
      w.send("hb");
    }
}; 
w.onopen = function() { 
    // do nothing 
};

function subscriptionChanged() {
  if (this.checked === true) {
    // subscribe
    w.send(this.value);
  } else {
    // unsubscribe
    w.send('-'+ this.value);
  }
}

function buildCheckbox(v) {
  var cb = document.createElement('input');
  cb.setAttribute('type','checkbox');
  cb.setAttribute('value', v);
  cb.setAttribute('id', 'c-' + v);
  cb.addEventListener('change', subscriptionChanged);
  return cb;
}

function buildLabel(v) {
  var lbl = document.createElement('label');
  lbl.textContent = v;
  lbl.setAttribute('for', 'c-' + v);
  return lbl;
}

function subscription(v) {
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  container.appendChild(buildCheckbox(v)); 
  container.appendChild(buildLabel(v));
  control.appendChild(container);
}

// setup which data to subscribe to
['155-questions-active',
 '1-review-dashboard-update',
 '1-questions-newest-tag-c',
 '1-questions-newest-tag-c++',
 '1-questions-newest-tag-c#',
 '1-questions-newest-tag-java',
 '1-questions-newest-tag-javascript',
 '1-questions-newest-tag-php',
 '1-questions-newest-tag-mysql',
 '1-questions-newest-tag-python',
 '1-questions-newest-tag-ruby',
 '1-questions-newest-tag-html',
 '1-questions-newest-tag-css'
].forEach(subscription);
```

```html
subscribe
<div id="control">

</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

I reverse engineered this by looking up the [full-anon.en.js](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/full-anon.en.js?v=50ccd5d69196) on the dev.sstatic.net which turns out to reveal this method:

```
function unsubscribe(data) {
    log("unsubscribing " + data);

    var index = $.inArray(data, channelBuffer);
    if (index == -1) return;

    channelBuffer.splice(index, 1);

    // unsubscribe happens immediately and is sent directly
    if (socket == null || !socket.isOpen()) return;
    socket.send("-" + data);
}
```

Comment: great! thanks... will check the full-anon js file! thanks

Comment: Answers like that make me sad because we don't have bounties here in MSO.

Comment: If answers make you sad you should down vote @Zanon ... oh wait ...